# Easy AI Pathfinding Library

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I have written games with Game Maker but wish to write a Flash game using ActionScript 3.

In Game Maker it was simple to have a character instance look for the closest enemy, turn, and move towards it -- the game engine took care of the hard stuff.

I do game development for fun on my spare time and don't have a desire to become an expert on A* pathfinding algorithms.  I just want something like:

```
mob.MoveToClosestEnemy();
```

Am I asking for too much or is there a library that provides such a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no built in AS3 library that will handle every aspect of path-finding so your options are to look for a 3rd party library via google and use that or write your own A* algorithm.

If you want to write your own, this is a very good introduction to pathfinding with a great animated example:
http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2012/11/26/the-basics-of-pathfinding-animated-example/

Note: It's not a simple technique and you will need relative experience using AS3 to fully understand it all.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote Daedalus Lib, a complete opensource AS3 pathfinding library based on delaunay triangulation. You have everything to easily build an environment (even use of bitmap), request pathfinding on it, sample paths... It is completely dynamic, accurate and fast.

You can see demos here:
http://totologic.blogspot.fr/2013/12/introducing-daedalus-lib_19.html

Download sources and wiki:
https://code.google.com/p/daedalus-lib/

Enjoy!

AFTER EDIT:

First thing. while Game Maker is all in 1 tool dedicated to one task (making games), Flash is a more general plateform ; you can develop games but also applications.

It means than in Flash, you have 2 choices:

1 - you choose a complete game engine library that will implement display, physics, controls... (and maybe pathfinding). Such libs exist (Flixel, Flashpunk...), you just need to check the features of them and to choose the more suitable for your need.

2: you build your own game engine. It doesn't mean you must code everything from scratch. You can compose with many libraries dedicated to single tasks, like Starling for 2D display, Away3D for 3D display, Box2D for physics... It is more difficult, because you really must understand the underlying concepts in the libraries and have experience with game architecture, but that approach is more powerful and flexible.

So Daedalus Lib is dedicated  for people working with the second approach. It is designed to be a component of your own game engine ; you can combine it with Box2D and Starling for example.

Beginning from that, I designed Daedalus to be easy to use while staying flexible.

For example, you can inject your level design into Daedalus Lib simply by the use of a bitmap, like that:

```
var myLevel:DDLSMesh;
myLevel = DDLSBitmapMeshFactory.buildFromBmpData(myBitmap.bitmapData);
```

Then define an entity, that will play the role of your mob:

```
var myMob:DDLSEntityAI = new DDLSEntityAI();
myMob.radius = 5;
myMob.x = 132; // current x
myMob.y = 224; // current y
```

Finally ask for a path for your mob inside your level:

```
var path:Vector.<Number> = new Vector.<Number>();
var myPathfinder:DDLSPathFinder = new DDLSPathFinder();
myPathfinder.entity = myMob;
myPathfinder.mesh = myLevel;
myPathfinder.findPath(yourGoalX, yourGoalY, path);
```

After that, your variable *path* will contain the coords of the generated path for your mob to reach your goal, avoiding collisions with the level you defined in the bitmap.
Up to you to use these coords directly on a MovieClip through an enterFrame to make your mob moving on screen, or use it to change the speed of a body in a physic simulation.

Comment: Instead of plugging your library and leaving it at that, a good answer would demonstrate (with code, in this same answer) how to solve the original question.  Answers that **only link** to related material are discouraged on SO.

Comment: The request was "is there a library that provides such a thing?". It was not a request for code sampling.

So I answered by providing direct links to code source and doc.

But if you have any question that I could answer with code, you can ask :)

Comment: @Logic Yes, but please also be aware that this question from 2013 no longer meets the current SO quality guidelines; specifically, questions seeking libraries, references, tutorials, etc. are now considered **off-topic**.  Your answer fits the question, but the question is no longer appropriate.  The SO standards for answers currently discourage new answers (regardless of the question) from simply linking to external content without summarizing that content in the answer itself.

Comment: P.S. An example of how to implement the OP's desired `mob.MoveToClosestEnemy()` method using your library would be a great way to improve this answer.

Comment: Fantastic improvement!